# Changing UIImage image property with the image name set in a dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm building a simple app which you click on a button and the image change randomly but I also want to add a label which describes the image so I created a dictionary contains the `["fileName":"Description"]` but when I try changing the image I get an error:

> "Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : String]' with an index of type 'Int'"

```
var randomNumber = 0
let arrayOfImages : [String:String] = ["ball1":"yes","ball2":"no","ball3":"ask again later","ball4":"the answer is yes","ball5":"i dont know"]

func rollButton() {
    randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0...4)
    ballImage.image = UIImage(named: arrayOfImages[randomNumber])
}
```

How can I change the `UIImage.image` using a `Dictionary`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
ballImage.image = UIImage(named: arrayOfImages[randomNumber])
```

with

```
ballImage.image = UIImage(named: Array(arrayOfImages.keys)[randomNumber])
```

As you can't subscript a dictionary it's for arrays , A good practice is to create

```
struct Item { 
    let imageName:String 
    let des:String 
}

let arr = [Item(imageName: "ball1", des: "con1"),Item(imageName: "ball2", des: "con2"),Item(imageName: "ball3", des: "con3")]
let ran = arr[Int.random(in: 0...2)]
ballImage.image = ran.imageName
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a list of `[String: String]`, so you should access it using a key (String) and not a number (Int).

So you should correct this:

```
ballImage.image = UIImage(named: arrayOfImages["ball\(randomNumber)"])
```